# C/C++ Get key pressed without polling

Tags: c++, c, io, kernel, polling

I am learning C/C++ and I recently created a key-logger, mostly because it is a simple project for learning. So what I do is run `GetAsynKeyState()` in a loop to check for the status of a key. When I check the CPU its cycles spike because well; I am constantly running a loop with a conditional in it.

It seems to me wasteful to do this kind of thing, I am sure that bigger more advanced software don't use this kind of technique.

**Question:** When a key is pressed an interrupt is created for the kernel to handle. Can my program be 'woken up' like the kernel is, or is the only solution constantly checking for a pressed key? What would a professional application do?

Additionally, programming languages implement en event listener, how do they accomplish this, polling or some other magic?

Comment: Which OS? I'm assuming this is Windows.

Comment: When you’re polling with `GetAsyncKeyState`, are you sleeping at all in between checks?

Comment: @minitech Yes I am making it sleep. Still my question is moslty about the kind of procedure applications would use because a constant loop seems to me a little crazy, don't you think?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes Windows but mainly I ask about the general concept applications use to do this kind of thing.

Comment: In my experience, a small sleep in there cut the CPU usage down to about nothing. Anyway, hooks will get you an event-based solution.

Comment: @chris I am a newb, what are 'hooks'?

Comment: @boompow, There's a lot of info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx A low level keyboard hook is the easiest global kind to get started with for keyboard input since it doesn't require a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

A hook is a mechanism for intercepting events (for ex., mouse actions or keystrokes) before they reach an application. Functions that receive these events are called filter functions (see `MyKbHook` bellow. ) In order to be called a filter function  must be attached to a Windows hook (see `SetWindowHookEx` below).

If a hook has more than one filter function attached, Windows maintains a chain of filter functions. The last installed function is at the beginning of the chain, and the first installed function is at the end.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyKbHook( int nId, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
   char keyPressed;

   KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pHook = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
   switch( wParam )
   {
       case WM_KEYUP: 
       {
          //get the key code
          keyPressed= (char)pHook->vkCode;
       }
       break;
       default:
           return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nId, wParam, lParam );
       break;
   }


   //Each function implementing a hook must call the next hook in chain before return
   return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nId, wParam, lParam);
}


// somewhere in your code where you want start tracking
    HHOOK hookKB = SetWindowHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD,(HOOKPROC)MyKbHook,hInst,0);

// when you do not need it anymore you SHOULD uninstall it
 UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookKB);
```

Answer (score 0):

The professional method depends from OS to OS. On Windows, you'd just use windows messages. Depending on your exact need, you'd use typically `WM_CHAR` or `WM_KEYDOWN`.  A lot easier than hooks.